# Is this sufficient to prove that a multiple of a Lipschitz function is also Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis

If we have a Lipschitz function, $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $h(x) = 3f(x)$, can I show that $h: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is also Lipschitz by the following?

Assume $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Lipschitz. Then, there is $K > 0$ such that for all $x,y \in S$ with $|f(x) – f(y)| < \frac{K}{3}|x – y|$. Then, choose for $|3f(x) – 3f(y)| < 3|f(x) – f(y)| < \frac{3K}{3}|x – y| = K|x – y|$. So $3f(x) = h(x)$ is also Lipschitz.

I feel there is a hole in my logic somewhere but cannot grasp quite where.

Comment: Seems OK to me.  Where do you think there might be a hole?

Comment: What is the set $S$?

Comment: Just any arbitrary set. I don't think it matters too much since we don't have a specific function in mind. Also, that's good to hear I was thinking I cannot find any mistakes I made.

Comment: Okay, from your context, it is an arbitrary *subset* of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly fine. Indeed note that the space of Lipschitz functions is a vector space, hence it makes perfectly sense.